# Write a method that relies on types having common property

Tags: typescript

I have a method that sortes objects inside the array by name, now I would like to reuse the method to sort another type of objects that both have in common `name` property, however, the rest of the properties are not the same.

Can u please if it's possible to update this code below to achieve the following result in TS?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AQSgXigbwFBSFQB2AhgLYQBcUAzsAE4CWxA5gUQPYDuxACg06QGoNDU6IUwDoR79Bw0ACEaxAK7k4EBngC%20ePKEixJqJVlwySFanUYt2RKHIFDtoAKLjT0py4XuIABiNADaALp6BsicxPRQpAwMpCAwAGbwSKhiJlnoERahVvhOTmSUNADk5RCVADRWfryuiiA5OLoNpVzNASIgKlAADFb6kXgxccAJSSnpmVKDC2YF2EVOJd3WFVDVNvWNPfJu-V64nYeyvSegIVARo3jjk-G0nCJKIAByNgBKELQ1AAbYAwBgAE20Fk2hFItGQEGI4JoAFoAIxdIiQ%20GI5FQDFWCAARzUpCBNBG%20jwaTUxFQTFiUAA%20jFyGBEhAfpRaFAABRWUg0UjEECYwhwIUisV0d6giHaHLqTTaaVvERgyEMQZKrQ6ACUlicL2mpC50GwpAAdDVLcBOAAZHjaADCcIgvL1VmNUDgZoscGtNltDqdDFdtHdnqsTDSfNNNigAB4fWaDTDSgwIMA1AxiDL1fKGGhRlAIECI1AY3zfQnk-HKGnLlBM9nc-m5ZqlI8rC2c3m1cBPmb-oCQRrtJbiaSgVFqbT6YyB0ObImACqlgAewFxPIiAD447MQDRV42nIlkiBLQPebzBQkpT7JSADZgD%20mnL22yzOGyOWbaDvOofWApdvj%20AFgQ7Cc4QRJFQNlZdKBHKDxwYS1sTg8FPScXRPSpMCzTvI95h8NBPUImxiMvUi8iUT0gA)

```
type ObjectA = {
    name: string
    ownPropertyA: object
    ownPropertyB: number
}

type ObjectB = {
    name: string
    ownPropertyE: object
    ownPropertyF: []
}

const arrayOfObjectA: ObjectA[] = [
    {
        name: 'name',
        ownPropertyA: {},
        ownPropertyB: 0
    }
]

const arrayOfObjectB: ObjectB[] = [
    {
        name: 'name',
        ownPropertyE: {},
        ownPropertyF: []
    }
]

const sortByNameResultOrder = {
    ascend: -1,
    descend: 1,
    equal: 0
}

function _compareNames (
    a: any,
    b: any,
    sortOrderA: number,
    sortOrderB: number
) {
    const aName = a.name.toLowerCase()
    const bName = b.name.toLowerCase()

    if (aName < bName) {
        return sortOrderA
    } else if (bName < aName) {
        return sortOrderB
    }

    return sortByNameResultOrder.equal
}

function sortByName<T extends []> (array: T) {
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        return _compareNames(a, b, sortByNameResultOrder.ascend, sortByNameResultOrder.descend)
    })
}

sortByName(arrayOfObjectA)
sortByName(arrayOfObjectB)
```

Comment: Your playground link isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function sorts objects by their `name` property the `a` and `b` parameters aren't expected to be any type, but rather an object with a `name` property

```
function _compareNames<T extends Record<'name', string>>(
    a: T,
    b: T,
    sortOrderA: number,
    sortOrderB: number
) {
 // ....
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=35&ssc=1&pln=40&pc=4#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AQSgXigbwFBSFQB2AhgLYQBcUAzsAE4CWxA5gUQPYDuxACg06QGoNDU6IUwDoR79Bw0ACEaxAK7k4EBngC+ePKEixJqJVlwySFanUYt2RKHIFDtoAKLjT0py4XuIABiNADaALp6BsicxPRQpAwMpCAwAGbwSKhiJlnoERahVvhOTmSUNADk5RCVADRWfryuiiA5OLoNpVzNASIgKlAADFb6kXgxccAJSSnpmVKDC2YF2EVOJd3WFVDVNvWNPfJu-V64nYeyvSegIVARo3jjk-G0nCJKIAByNgBKELQ1AAbYAwBgAE20Fk2hFItGQEGI4JoAFoAIxdIiQ+GI5FQDFWCAARzUpCBNBG+jwaTUxFQTFiUAA+jFyGBEhAfpRaAAeAAqUAgAA9gLjaFB-jEITy9pR6nZmGwAHxKgAUVlIND5mMIcC1Oro71BEO0OXUmm0BreIjBkIYg3NWh0AEpLE4XtNSFzoNhSAA6Gp+4CcAAyPG0AGE4RBVc6rB6oHBvRY4AGbEHQ+GGFHaDG41YmGkoKqvTYoDzE97XTDSgwIMA1AxiIabSaGGhRoKgbmoIXi0myxXS5Rq5coHWG02W8a7UpHlYJ43m9bgJ9vf9ASDbdo-cTSUCotTafTGSu1zZ+YKRWKJSh3uCZTV5fRFawVcXEskQFqIqOnJ+Uj9FdVRLGhSGIEA6kTMCINdTAlTdLZFynFlODZDlvVoEsoLgKCz2+P4AWBGcdzhBEkTwo1z0oDdiO3Bg-WxcjwTjJxdDjKl8O9EtZlSDIfDQOMuJsHiv3mHwlDjIA)